# Passing values from JavaScript function to a JSP scriplet and back

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Why isn't this code working? `newString` always gets `null` value. How can I fetch the value of `someString` in the `<% %>` section?

```
<script>
    function func(someInput)
    {                                                                                                                 
        var someString = someInput;                                                                                                                                   
        <% String newString = request.getParameter("someString");%>
        alert("can you see this string? <%=newString%>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If this is in an external JS file, the file needs to be a JSP too

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get the variable: `newString` in your JSP file , you should make sure that you are accessing the page(named `your_file.jsp`) with this url:

   `http://your_host:8080/your_file.jsp?someString=foo`
2. writing the code using mixed languages ( JSP mixed javascript in your case) is very difficult. keep in mind that:

   > the JSP scripts will be parsed before the javascript file.